# gradle build failing with exception failed for task ':compileJava'. byteBuddy library issue

Tags: java, gradle, build, compilation, byte-buddy

Hello and thank you ahead of time for any help.

Firstly, I do know that other people have had this issue before and I've tried the solutions in all of their discussions and none of them have worked for me.

Basically, I'm trying to setup "gradle build" in the project folder for a java eclipse project so that I can begin to code an agent. I'm receiving an issue with getting the program to recogninse byteBuddy which is already in my lib folder and added to my dependencies in my gradle file.

This is my first time working with both gradle and byteBuddy.

When i try to gradle build in the project folder its says this:

Excecution failed for task ':compileJava'.

When i use --info, it provided me more details by saying:

All input files are out-of-date for incremental task ':compileJava'. Full recompilation is required because no incremental change information is available.

It proceeds to say:

....path.... java\main.java:4: error: package net.bytebuddy.agent does not exist
import net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent;

I have done a bunch of research into the problem and I've seen things that it could be like java version mismatches with gradle, incorrect JAVA_HOME settings, and why the program doesn't pick up the jars that are clearly in my library.

I don't know if my issue is related to the above mentioned, but I haven't yet found other potential issues relating to my problem.

I am using:
Java eclipse,
java 1.8.0_212 (my JAVA_HOME is set to this),
gradle-5.4.1,
byteBuddy 1.2.12 library,
asm-7.1 library (which is said to be needed to run byteBuddy), and
jackcess 2.1.11 library (which i'm not sure is related to the issue but it came up in the gradle build before i tried bytebuddy with the same issue)

EDIT: I am running Windows 7 Professional

Here is my main file that was mentioned in the error message above. In the above code, I'm trying to get the commented out area to work, but eclipse isn't recognizing the ByteBuddy import:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import net.bytebuddy.ByteBuddy;
import net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.FixedValue;
import net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers;


public class main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        mainFrame newBegining = new mainFrame();
        newBegining.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        newBegining.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        newBegining.setVisible(true);
    }

    /*Class<?> dynamicType = new ByteBuddy()
              .subclass(Object.class)
              .method(ElementMatchers.named("toString"))
              .intercept(FixedValue.value("Hello World!"))
              .make()
              .load(getClass().getClassLoader())
              .getLoaded();

            assertThat(dynamicType.newInstance().toString(), is("Hello World!"));*/
}
```

Here are relevant snippets from my gradle file below(I believe they could be based on that I edited them in attempts to fix the issue and they were mentioned in other potential resolutions):

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    flatDir { dirs 'lib' }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.1'
    compile 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.9.12'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

compileJava {
    options.debug = true
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
            'Main-Class': 'main',
            'Premain-Class': 'searchAgent.searchAgent',
            'Agent-Class': 'searchAgent.searchAgent',
            'Can-Redefine-Classes': 'true',
            'Can-Retransform-Classes': 'true',
        )
        from configurations.runtime.collect { zipTree(it) }
    }
```

As far as i understand, I think the issue relates to gradle's ability to recognize my byteBuddy library, but I'm not entirely sure.

I feel like the answer is something small, but i haven't been able to pin it.

Comment: Seems like an ordering issue. The file might only exist after a target that is supposed to exist earlier.

Comment: Are you able to identify where? I can't see it.